# Make Nginx escape spaces in $http_user_agent when logging

Tags: nginx

If the Nginx `log_format` configuration directive includes the `$http_user_agent` variable, then the value is logged with spaces included. For example,

```
log_format myformat '$http_referer';
```

logs lines such as:

`Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)`

I don’t want the spaces, and would much prefer:

`Mozilla/5.0%20(compatible;%20bingbot/2.0;%20+http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)`

The reason for this is to make it much easier to parse the logfiles later, as they will have space-separated fields (but never spaces within the fields), which can easily be split apart using the `.split_whitespace()` method in Rust, or `Fields` function in Go, etc.

Does anyone know a way to get Nginx to escape spaces in variables used in the log_format configuration directive?

Comment: You could log in json format

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, such a feature does not exist.

There are also other entries which include spaces, like the `"GET / HTTP 1.1"` in the `access.log`.

The proper way to parse `access.log` is to first make each string embedded in quotes a single item, and then split all items in the line by spaces.

There are plenty of open-source log analyzers available, you can look into how they implement the reading of `access.log` files.